# i have 3 screens and wanna display the name that the user enter it on the 3ed screen kivymd

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

i have 3 screens
the second one include textfield who user can enter his name
and wanna display the name that the user enter it on the 3ed screen like a label
like this :
welcome +'the name that user enter it'
so the problem im tired to get the value that user entred and displayed on anathor screen

and this is my code

```
WindowManager:
    WelcomeScreen:
    UsernameScreen:
    DobScreen:

<WelcomeScreen>:
    name: 'welcomescreen'
    MDLabel:
        text:'welcome screen'
        font_style:'H2'
        halign:'center'
        pos_hint:{'center_y':0.65}
    MDFloatingActionButton:
        icon:'android'
        md_bg_color:app.theme_cls.primary_color
        user_font_size: '60sp'
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.32}
        on_press:
            root.manager.current='usernamescreen'
            root.manager.transition.direction='left'
    MDProgressBar:
        value:30
        pos_hint:{'center_y':0.02}
<UsernameScreen>: 
    name:'usernamescreen'
    MDFloatingActionButton:
        icon:'arrow-left'
        md_bg_color:app.theme_cls.primary_color
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.15, 'center_y':0.1}
        user_font_size: '45sp'
        on_press:
            root.manager.current='welcomescreen'
            root.manager.transition.direction='right'
    MDFloatingActionButton:
        id:disabled_button
        disabled:True
        icon:'arrow-right'                
        md_bg_color:app.theme_cls.primary_color
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.85, 'center_y':0.1}
        user_font_size: '45sp'
        on_press:
            root.manager.current='dob'
            root.manager.transition.direction='left'
    MDProgressBar:
        value:60
        pos_hint:{'center_y':0.02}
    MDLabel:
        text:'username'                                 
        font_style:'H2'
        halign:'center'
        pos_hint:{'center_y':0.75}
    MDTextField:
        id:username_text_field  
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.6}
        size_hint:(0.7,0.1)           
        hint_text:'user name'
        icon_right:'account' 
        icon_right_color:app.theme_cls.primary_color    
    MDFloatingActionButton:   
        icon:'account-plus'   
        md_bg_color:app.theme_cls.primary_color 
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.35}    
        user_font_size: '50sp'
        on_press:
            app.check_username()
<DobScreen>:    
    name:'dob'
    MDLabel:
        id:profile_name
        text:'dob screen'                                 
        font_style:'H2'
        halign:'center'
        pos_hint:{'center_y':0.75}
```

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '300') 
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '560')
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton,MDFloatingActionButton
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore
from kivymd.uix.picker import MDDatePicker


class WelcomeScreen(Screen):
    pass
class UsernameScreen(Screen):
    pass
class DobScreen(Screen):
    pass
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class NewApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.strng=Builder.load_file('screens.kv')
        return self.strng
    def check_username(self):
        self.username_text=self.strng.get_screen('usernamescreen').ids.username_text_field.text
        username_check_false=True
        try:
            int(self.username_text)
        except:
            username_check_false=False
        if username_check_false or self.username_text.split() == []:
            cancel_btn_username_dialogue = MDFlatButton(text='Retry',on_release=self.close_username_dialogue)
            self.dialog= MDDialog(title='Invalid Username',text='plase enter ur name',size_hint=(0.7,0.2),buttons=[cancel_btn_username_dialogue])
            self.dialog.open()
        else:
            self.strng.get_screen('usernamescreen').ids.disabled_button.disabled =False
            
    
NewApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

**inside UsernameScreen**

```
class UsernameScreen(widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        supper().__init__(**kwargs)
    def check_username(self):
        self.username_field = self.ids.ID_username_field
```

**to use it inside file.kv**

```
<UsernameScreen>
     MDTextField:
        id: ID_username_text_field
```

**inside DobScreen class**

```
class DobScreen(widget):
    username = StringProperty()
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        supper().__init__(**kwargs) 
        self.username = Usernamescreen.username_field    #### the variable u need from the second class(second screen)
```

**in the kv file where the label is displayed**

```
<DobScreen>
   #### ur widgets###
   #########
   Label:
       text: root.username
```

***Piece of advice**: try to be a bit more reliable on python and split the work between kv lang and python*